# Найти единственное число в бинарном дереве

Tags: java, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

Есть некоторое бинарное дерево и каждый элемент в нем содержится дважды кроме одного. Его-то и нужно найти)

Требуется написать алгоритм поиска такого числа за логарифмическую сложность и при этом создавать новые массивы и коллекции нельзя.
На вход подается корень дерева

Пример [2,2,1]-> 1,[4,1,2,1,2]-> 4,[1]-> 1

Comment: Какие ваши мысли и где попытки решения? И какое именно бинарное дерево?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас на входе неотсортированный массив, который ещё *как-то* следует преобразовать в бинарное дерево, и это преобразование вряд ли будет иметь логарифмическую сложность.

А найти единственный уникальный непарный элемент в массиве, где должны содержаться только пары можно с помощью операции XOR со сложностью O(N), просто "сложив" все элементы такого массива.

- Реализация с циклом:

```java
public static int findUnique(int ... pairs) {
    int result = pairs[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        result ^= pairs[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

- Реализация с использованием `IntStream::reduce` (Stream API)

```java
public static int findUnique(int ... pairs) {
    return Arrays.stream(pairs).reduce((x, y) -> x ^ y).getAsInt();
}
```